# Find the numbers that do not exist in a String

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq, textbox

The problem is as follows: I have a set of numbers from 1 to 80.
In `Textbox1.Text` I have the following numbers:

```
TextBox1.Text = "1,4,5,6,7,8,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,25,28,29,31,33,
                 34,35,36,37,39,40,41,45,46,47,48,49,51,53,54,55,57,59,60,61,62,
                 63,64,66,67, 68,69,70,71,72,73,75,76,77,78,79,80"
```

How can I display, in `TextBox2.Text`, the numbers that are not in `TextBox1`, from 1 to 80?

```
TextBox2.Text = "2,3,9,10,11 and so on..."
```

Comment: Please show us what you have done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two examples not using LINQ.

This one uses a Dictionary and a List:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim present As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Boolean)
    For Each strValue As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(",".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If Integer.TryParse(strValue, n) Then
            present.Add(n, True)
        End If
    Next

    Dim notPresent As New List(Of Integer)
    For i As Integer = 1 To 80
        If Not present.ContainsKey(i) Then
            notPresent.Add(i)
        End If
    Next

    TextBox2.Text = String.Join(",", notPresent.ToArray)
End Sub
```

This one simply uses two Lists:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim present As New List(Of Integer)
    For Each strValue As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(",".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If Integer.TryParse(strValue, n) Then
            present.Add(n)
        End If
    Next
    present.Sort() ' optional; if you need these sorted for something else

    Dim notPresent As New List(Of Integer)
    For i As Integer = 1 To 80
        If present.IndexOf(i) = -1 Then
            notPresent.Add(i)
        End If
    Next

    TextBox2.Text = String.Join(",", notPresent.ToArray)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering that the question references *numbers*, so the resulting values might be used somewhere as actual numbers (not just as a string representation of numbers) you could:

- Extract the values from the source string in a `List(Of Integer)`
- Create a `List(Of Integer)` initialized with a number of elements corresponding to the maximum value of the source numbers using [Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range)
- Filter the full list of numbers using the partial one using [Enumerable.Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except)
- Convert the resulting `List(Of Integer)` to a comma-separated string of values if required.

**Note**:
I'm supposing that the source string has already been validated. If it's not, use [Integer.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse) instead of [Integer.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse). A related sample code is in [this (so very similar) question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964073/7444103).

---

```
Dim BaseNumbers As List(Of Integer) = 
    txtInput.Split(","c).Select(Function(n) Integer.Parse(n)).OrderBy(Function(n) n).ToList()

'Get the List of missing numbers in the source range of values
Dim ResultList As List(Of Integer) = 
    Enumerable.Range(1, BaseNumbers.Max()).Except(BaseNumbers).ToList()

'Convert to string the resulting List
Dim resultString = String.Join(",", ResultList)
```

Comment: System cannot be converted a string to -1 dimmensional array. Error(  Dim ResultString = String.Join(",", ResultList)

Comment: You need a reference to `System.Linq`. Depending on the VB.Net version, you might need to use `String.Join(",", ResultList.AsEnumerable())`. If it's still not working for you, you need to tell me what VB.Net version (or Visual Studio version) you're using.

Comment: Visual Basic 2008

Comment: These methods are all available from .Net version 3.5. You need, as already mentioned, to add a reference to `System.Linq`, `System.Collections` and `System.Collections.Generic`. Open up the `Project -> Properties -> References -> Imported Namespaces` and add what's missing. If you're targeting .Net 2.0, you need to chage this too, upgrading to 3.5 at least. This VB.Net version is **very** old. You'll miss many of the solutions proposed by StackOverflow answers. You need to upgrade (unless, of course, it's some school assignment).